# override AdminSite make admin.py another app doesn't show at django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

On my project, there are multiple app, so i also have admin.py each folder. Here are some of my admin.py

api/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Message

@admin.register(Message)
class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['source','name','created']
    list_filter = ['source','created']
    search_fields = ['message']
```

dummy/admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from dummy.forms import MyAdminLoginForm

# export admin.py another app
from api.models import Message
from api.admin import MessageAdmin

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    login_form = MyAdminLoginForm
    login_template = 'dummy/templates/admin/login.html'

site = MyAdminSite()
site.register(Message,MessageAdmin)
```

Since i wanna use captcha on django admin login, i should override the login form that inherit from AdminSite via dummy/admin.py. After that i registering the custom login on the main url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from dummy.admin import site
admin.site = site

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
]
```

You can see that i re registering the api/admin.py on the dummy/admin.py, i did it because if i didn't re registering the api/admin.py, it won't be show at the django admin. what should i do to make the admin.py another app doesn't need to be re register like it used to be when i use custom login form that inherit from AdminSite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just patch and use the original `admin.site`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.login_form = MyAdminLoginForm
admin.site.login_template = 'dummy/templates/admin/login.html'
```